# When scrolling the ag-grid the header goes to the opposite direction

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When scrolling the ag-grid the header goes in the opposite direction.

This occurs when using RTL grid only

Please see the attached.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This bug again appear on Chrome 85 (because chrome change RTL calculation layout)

[Chrome 85 Update breaks the ag-grid ui and scroll in RTL](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4048)

Ag-Grid fixed on version 24.0.0

Old version like `21.2.2` or so on change path of `Utils.ts` file and use code

Create agGrid.ts on `/src/agGrid.ts` and copy below snippet

```js
/**
 * RTL scrolling breaks with Chrome 85
 * Fix Version: 24.0.0
 * File: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/community-modules/core/src/ts/utils/dom.ts
 * commit: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/commit/acffa118e0c705d17786377bd43a9fca247cdf72
 */

import { Utils } from "ag-grid-community/dist/lib/utils/general";

let rtlNegativeScroll: boolean;
export function isRtlNegativeScroll(): boolean {
    if (typeof rtlNegativeScroll === "boolean") {
        return rtlNegativeScroll;
    }

    const template = document.createElement("div");
    template.style.direction = "rtl";
    template.style.width = "1px";
    template.style.height = "1px";
    template.style.position = "fixed";
    template.style.top = "0px";
    template.style.overflow = "hidden";
    template.dir = "rtl";
    template.innerHTML = /* html */
        `<div style="width: 2px">
            <span style="display: inline-block; width: 1px"></span>
            <span style="display: inline-block; width: 1px"></span>
        </div>`;

    document.body.appendChild(template);

    template.scrollLeft = 1;
    rtlNegativeScroll = template.scrollLeft === 0;
    document.body.removeChild(template);

    return rtlNegativeScroll;
}

Utils.setScrollLeft = (element: HTMLElement, value: number, rtl: boolean): void => {
    if (rtl) {
        // Chrome and Safari when doing RTL have the END position of the scroll as zero, not the start
        if (isRtlNegativeScroll()) {
            value *= -1;
        } else if (Utils.isBrowserSafari() || Utils.isBrowserChrome()) {
            value = element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth - value;
        }
    }
    element.scrollLeft = value;
};
Utils.getScrollLeft = (element: HTMLElement, rtl: boolean): number => {
    let scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;

    if (rtl) {
        // Absolute value - for FF that reports RTL scrolls in negative numbers
        scrollLeft = Math.abs(scrollLeft);

        if (Utils.isBrowserChrome() && !isRtlNegativeScroll()) {
            scrollLeft = element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth - scrollLeft;
        }
    }

    return scrollLeft;
};
```

import snippet to `main.ts`

`import "./agGrid";`